# Is this automorphism the identity map

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $f: A \rightarrow A$ an surjective homomorphism, let $a$ be a ideal of $A$ then if $f(a)\subseteq a$ then it's $f$ is the identity map, or not necessary.

Comment: "Automorphism" implies that it is an isomorphism, so why add that it's surjective when this follows from the definition?  Just want to make sure you meant the right term.

Comment: Let $A= k[x,y]$, for some field $k$ and $f: x \mapsto y$, $y \mapsto x$.

On the other hand, you can also win a lot of trivial counterexamples by taking the ideal to be $0$.

Comment: Do you mean that for *every* ideal $a$, $f(a)\subseteq a$?

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $f:k[x,y]\to k[x,y]$ switch $x$ and $y$. Then ideals like $(x,y)$ and $(xy)$ are preserved, but $f$ is not the identity.